# ajax request ember passing through component

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-components, ember-controllers

i just wanna get value from json request in ember services from component.
this is my code

**forecast-weather.js (services)**

```
import Ember from 'ember';  
    export default Ember.Service.extend({
      findWeatherCurrent:function (lat,lng) {
        return Ember.$.getJSON('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/22b106924ed7e3bcde76608f7f064585/'+ lat +','+lng+'?exclude=minutely,hourly,daily,flags&units=si');
      },
      findWeatherDaily:function (lat,lng) {
        return Ember.$.getJSON('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/22b106924ed7e3bcde76608f7f064585/'+ lat +','+lng+'?exclude=minutely,hourly,currently,flags&units=si');
      },
      findWeatherHourly:function (lat,lng) {
        return Ember.$.getJSON('https://api.darksky.net/forecast/22b106924ed7e3bcde76608f7f064585/'+ lat +','+lng+'?exclude=minutely,daily,currently,flags&units=si');
      }
    });
```

**weather-display.js (component)**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  forecastWeather:Ember.inject.service(),
  willRender(){
    let lat = this.get('lat');
    let lng = this.get('lng');
    this.get('forecastWeather').findWeatherCurrent(lat,lng).then(data => {
      this.set('currents', data);
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
});
```

**jsonRespon**

```
{

    "latitude": 37.8267,
    "longitude": -122.4233,
    "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "offset": -7,
    "currently": {
        "time": 1489488513,
        "summary": "Clear",
        "icon": "clear-night",
        "nearestStormDistance": 47,
        "nearestStormBearing": 87,
        "precipIntensity": 0,
        "precipProbability": 0,
        "temperature": 13.54,
        "apparentTemperature": 13.54,
        "dewPoint": 8.59,
        "humidity": 0.72,
        "windSpeed": 0.87,
        "windBearing": 46,
        "visibility": 12.46,
        "cloudCover": 0.08,
        "pressure": 1016.58,
        "ozone": 279.62
    }

}
```

**weather-display.hbs**

```
<p id="word_on_change" class="font_black font-white word">{{currents.currently.windSpeed}}</p>
```

i just wanna passing that windspeed value from json to hbs template, but it doesnt working.
can anyone solve this :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle the result of `$.getJSON` its important to know your `jQuery` version. One of the most important changes in `jQuery 3` is that [jQuery.Deferred is now Promises/A+](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/) compatible.

Probably you are using a `jQuery` version pre `3.0`, which means you have to transform the `Deferred` to a `Promise` which can be done with `Ember.RSVP.resolve()`.

However this is *not your problem*!

### your actual problem

First I've build a [twiddle with your code](https://ember-twiddle.com/5234583e490b35048c2253b88e1744dc?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.weather-display.hbs). Consider doing this yourself next time ;-).
There you see the error in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.darksky.net/forecast/22b106924ed7e3bcde76608f7f064585/46.9483,7.4515?exclude=minutely,hourly,daily,flags&units=si. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

This is because darksky has [disabled CORS for their API](https://darksky.net/dev/docs/faq#cross-origin). This means you *can't access the API from in-Browser JavaScript directly*.

You have to request your own Webserver, which then can do the request to the darksky API.

Please [check the references about CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

#### But the request returns a `200 OK` in the dev tools or an HTTP debugger

Yes. This is how CORS works. The data is successfully returned to the Browser by the application, but because the CORS headers are missing the Browser *doesnt allow your Website to access the response*. This is a important security feature.

Comment: how to ensure about jquery version? It was written in `bower.json` at previous versions of ember.

Comment: The version is now [specified inside `ember-source` itself](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/package.json#L54).